# Null pointer assignment error while printing one of the string from array of strings

Tags: c++

```
void main()
{
    char *str[3];
    cin>>str[0];
    cin>>str[1];
    cout<<str[1];
}
```

Output:

> Hi
>
> Hello

After the output, it either hangs or gives me a null-pointer assignment error. Why is this?

Comment: Your pointers in the arrays have not been initialized.  You need to allocate memory for them before inputting.

Comment: Your problems will go away if you switch to `std::string` for text strings.  Try `std::string str[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated three pointers to char strings, but no memory for the actual strings. Until you understand pointers better, I suggest you just use something like this:

```
char one[10];
char two[10];
char three[10];

cin >> one;
cin >> two;
cout << two;
```

Comment: I suggest using `std::string` until pointers are better understood and necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `str[0]`, for example. This is a char pointer, or a pointer to one or more characters.

However, you haven't pointed it to anything. And so it constitutes undefined behavior to access a NULL or random address from your code.

You need to better understand pointers, and make sure your pointers actually point to something.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory for your C-Style strings.

Switch to `std::string` if you want to use strings without the memory allocation and deallocation hassles (to name a few).

Also, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main(void)
{
  string str[3];
  cin >> str[0];
  cin >> str[1];
  cin >> str[2];

  cout << "[0]: " << str[0] << "\n";
  cout << "[1]: " << str[1] << "\n";
  cout << "[2]: " << str[2] << "\n";

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also, consider using `std::vector` instead of arrays.